# Is this a condition for completely reducible representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have yet found anywhere the condition for a representation to be completely reducible. However. when I reach page 9 in Georgi's book Lie Algebras for Particle Physics, he said:

> $$D(x)(I-P) \ne (I-P)$$
>   so it is not completely reducible.

Is this a condition for completely reducible representation?

In particular, the entire page said:

> The integers form an infinite group under addition:
>   $$xy=x+y$$
>   Here's a representation:
>   $$D ( x ) = \left( \begin{array} { l l } { 1 } & { x } \\ { 0 } & { 1 } \end{array} \right)$$
>   This representation is reducible, but you can show that it is not completely reducible and is not equivalent to a unitary representation. It is reducible because
>   $$D(x)P=P$$
>   where
>   $$P = \left( \begin{array} { l l } { 1 } & { 0 } \\ { 0 } & { 0 } \end{array} \right)$$
>   However,
>   $$D(x)(I-P) \ne (I-P)$$
>   so it is not completely reducible.

But if the group is finite, it turns into a cyclic group (say 9 elements from $0$ to $9$, and every number exceeds $9$ get round-down to its 1st unit, i.e. $17$ to $7$), and is completely reducible, yes? Yet nothing changes, and $D(x)(I-P) \ne (I-P)$ still. What am I misunderstanding here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is correct. Perhaps that what Georgi had in mind was this: with respect to the usual inner product, $P$ and $I-P$ are orthogonal. Therefore, if the representations was completely reducible, then, since the space $\langle P\rangle$ spanned by $P$ is stable (that is, for each integer $x$ and each $M\in\langle P\rangle$, $D(x)M\in\langle P\rangle$), $\langle P\rangle^\perp$ is stable too. But $\langle P\rangle^\perp=\langle I-P\rangle$ and it turns out that it *isn't* stable.

It would be better to show (and that's not hard) that if $M\notin\langle P\rangle$, then $\langle M\rangle$ is not stable. This proves that the representation is not completely reducible.

Comment: But if the group is finite, it turns into a cyclic group (say 9 elements from $0$ to $9$, and every number exceeds $9$ get round-down to its 1st unit, i.e. $17$ to $7$), and is completely reducible, yes? Yet nothing changes, and $D(x)(I-P) \ne (I-P)$ still. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: @D.Tran What is the vector space in which your group acts then?

Comment: @D.Tran I don't know what you are talking about. The group action defined by Georgi that you mention is an action of the integers on $\mathbb{R}^2$. But, in your comment, you mentioned an action of a cyclic group. An action *where*? What's the vector space on which they act?

Comment: Oh yeah damn that's stupid of me. Okay, so I'd use $2$-dimensional vectors for both the finite and infinite groups? I mean both representation are $2$-dimensional matrix, so it'd be reasonable to use $2$-dimensional vectors? So yeah, I think they both acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would make things work. Is that okay?

Comment: @D.Tran No, it's not OK, because, although you can multiply an integer with a real number, you can't multiply an element of an arbitrary cyclic group with a real number.

Comment: I think I can see what I'm confusing about. So I think the cyclic group acting on a $2$-dim vector would rotate it around, yes? But I can't seem to connect that with the additive group, despite them both having $2$-dim matrix representation...
$$ $$
Could tell me where exactly does $D(x)$ of the additive group above act on? I can't see how these $D(x)$ can act on "integers", and when I put a vector $(1,0)$ there it'd just... stay $(1,0)$. Perhaps it'd shed light on my confusion...

Comment: @D.Tran In the case of the representation $D$, for each integer $x$, $D(x)$ actos on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The action of $x$ on the vector $(a,b)$ is $(a+xb,b)$.

Comment: I still fail to see how to prove a representation is completely reducible... If you don't mind, can you show it to me the method, on this additive group and a simple cyclic group, say $\mathbb{Z}_3$ or something? Thank you!

Comment: @D.Tran For that, the usual method is Weyl's [unitarian trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_trick). Please note that this is very removed from your original question. If you want more details, please post it as another question. And if my answer to this question was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.